# Is the lt03wifiue build the same as n1awifi?

Tags: lineageos, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I have an SM-P600, when I download TWRP it shows `lt03wifiue` for the build name. When I download LineageOS it shows [n1awifi](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/n1awifi) for the build name. Are these two the same builds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n2awifi` is the [TabPRO 10.1](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/n2awifi). You might be referring to `n1awifi` (which you correctly mentioned in your other question).

Sometime during development, some Samsung devices were reassigned codenames, and `lt03wifi` was renamed to `n1awifi` (see commit [here](https://github.com/zakooz/android_device_samsung_n1awifi/commit/3b425ffd94df67655fb0812f7aa168d6d1ebc8e4) and developer note [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=68518008&postcount=123)).

No need to worry as these are still the same device, and the ROM itself has provision for the name change (it checks match for either codenames when installing).

Comment: Yes, that was supposed to be n1awifi